# cmake specifying CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH cross-compiling

Tags: c, cmake, cross-compiling, yocto

I am using CMake with a custom toolchain that I built using yocto. My project consists of some libraries and few binaries that need to be linked against those libraries.
In the `CMakeLists` file of the binaries, there are the directives to link them with the libraries, e.g.

`FIND_LIBRARY(mylib NAMES mylib libmylib )`

After I had built `mylib` I'll put it in a common directory, says, `/home/user/common/lib/mylib.so`.

Then, I try to build the binary with

```
$ source /opt/poky-2.2.2/<path-to-environment-yocto-generated-file>
$ CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/common/lib/ cmake
```

cmake complains about not finding `mylib`. I discover that it's not finding it because is looking for `/home/user/common/lib/` under the sysroot folder.

I then tried to set `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY=BOTH` with no success.
I also tried to set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT` again, with no success (the `make install` command copies the library in `/usr/lib` and not under the sysroot folder).

How can I solve this? Which is the best practice? Install the needed libraries under the sysroots?

Thank you

Comment: While `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` could be an *environment* variable, the other variable you note (`CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY`, `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREIX`) should be *CMake* variables. Variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` could be set via `-D` option for `cmake`, but `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY` should be set in the toolchain file or, at the worst, in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Thank you for point out the fact that `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREIX` should be passed as an option with `-D`. This solves the install prefix issue. So, your advice is to install the libraries in the sysroot? I think that's not a good idea to mess around with `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY`

Comment: If you don't want to change `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY`, then the only way is to install the library under sysroot.